# Controller Constructors in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm a novice developer working on an existing Laravel app.  I'm looking through the project and I don't see any controllers constructed anywhere but the controllers all have constructor functions.

Is this a Laravel thing or am I just missing something?  Is controller instantiation handled in the routes or something?  If so, is it bad practice to call a controller constructor manually?(although I can't think of a case offhand where you would want to do this)

Comment: Question not clear. What do you mean by  I don't see any controllers constructed anywhere but the controllers all have constructor functions?

Comment: I mean all of the controllers in this project have a __construct function defined but I don't see any controllers constructed or instantiated anywhere in the project.

Comment: Can the person that downvoted this please explain to me why it's a bad question?  And do so in the future?  Just downvoting posts and running away doesn't help anything aside from possibly your fragile sense of superiority

Comment: The framework (service container) does the instantiation of the controllers for you, whenever your app needs an instance,  you don't have to care about that.

Comment: The constructor is called automatically by PHP itself when a new instance of a class is created. The router is asking the container for an instance of your controller. When it is created the constructor is called by PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: "The Laravel service container is used to resolve all Laravel controllers."

And: I often create a base controller in my apps, therefore I also have constructor in my extended controllers. It could also be useful to inject dependencies "properly" like shown in this example:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers